# Why can't I run Nunit tests from Visual Studio when colleague can?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, tdd, nunit

My code has NUnit tests. My colleague is able to run the tests from within Visual Studio on their desktop, however I can't run them on mine. When I try to use Test Explorer and "Run All", it just builds the project. Other options, such as Run Tests and Debug Tests also give the same result.

I have NUnit referenced in my project, why can't I run the tests from within Visual Studio?

Comment: Your colleague probably has an integrated NUnit test runner, like Resharper installed. If you don't have a license for these, it looks like you can still configure the good old [NUnit runner app to launch](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/running-or-debugging-nunit-tests-from.html).

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, Visual Studio doesn't have support for running tests built for the NUnit framework.  As has been said in the the comments, your colleague probably has some kind of add-in like Resharper installed which adds in [support for running Nunit tests](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html).

If you don't have a license for whatever tool they're using, then you can still have visual studio integrated support for running/debugging NUnit tests by installing the [NUnit Test Adapter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitTestAdapter/2.0.0).  This is a free plugin that you can install into your solution via NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

He may also be running the MS test adapter which you can get from the nunit site